# Node.js EJS Include feature is not working in my case

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I want to include header.ejs and footer.ejs into order.ejs.
The image below my folder structure.

[image]

But, I've got error. The code related to include in order.ejs is written below.

```
/// order.ejs

<%- include('../common/header.ejs') %>
```

I think my code is wrong. But I could not find any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Add Error Message

```
Error: ejs:18
    16|                         <tr>
    17|                             <td align="center" valign="top">
 >> 18|                                 <%- include('../common/header.ejs') %>
    19|                             </td>
    20|                         </tr>
    21|                         <tr>

Could not find the include file "../common/header.ejs" {"timestamp":"2022-05-14 13:58:57"}
```

Comment: You should share error message

Comment: I just updated error message.

Comment: Remove `.ejs` from filename option in `include`.

Comment: I removed '.ejs'. but it is not working too.

Comment: well i'm unable to find anything wrong in code provided by you ! are you using any static file server ? something like view-engine or something ? and can you please share error message shown in browser's developer's tool ? If these things fails to provide strong solution I will set bounty on this question.

Comment: Thank you @ht006 . The problem was ejs.comfile().

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this issue.
The problem was not a template, but the EJS function.

OLD Function:

```
ejs.compile()
```

NEW Function:

```
ejs.renderFile()
```

Comment: It is not helpful to anyone that this answer has nothing to do with the details in the question.  If you can draw a connection between the problem and the solution, then maybe it would be helpful to someone.